# Give/gave advice + every now and then

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense

Let's say you are describing your friend. And you say:

> Mr.B is our go to person. He **gives/gave** us advice every now and then.

I constructed a paragraph few months ago, and I used the past verb tense preceeding **''every now and then**''. Furthermore, If I use ''**gave''** here in this sentence, then it does not sound correct for me.(I'm not sure)

Do we put:

> simple present tense+''every now then''
>   or
>
> Past tense+''every now and then''

Comment: Both of them are correct, it just depends whether you mean "every now and then *now*" or only "every now and then *only in the past*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While **every now and then** suggests an activity that still continues intermittently, it is used both in the present tense and the past to mean **occasionally**.

It's quite legitimate to say both:

> We meet them every now and then

and

> We used to meet them every now and then.

So you can use either **give** or **gave** depending on whether Mr B still gives you advice.

Note that the expression **go-to person** requires a hyphen in the sense that you are using it.